# Dependence of ligh-matter strong coupling on incident laser power?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, quantum-electrodynamics, photonics, cavity-qed

is the light matter strong coupling dependent upon incident laser power? According to the following expression the strength of the vacuum Rabi splitting can be given as
$$\hbar\Omega_\mathrm{R}=2\hbar g
=2d\sqrt{N}\sqrt{\frac{\hbar\omega_\mathrm{c}}{2\varepsilon_0\mathcal{V}}}$$
Here $d$ is the distance between the cavity mirrors, $N$ is the number density , $\omega$ is the resonance frequency and $V$ is the field volume.

My query is that if the field volume a function of incident laser power. What kind of changes in coupling strength one can expect if laser power is increased or decreased?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strong **coupling**, as opposed to strong driving, does not depend on the incident laser power. In fact, it does not depend on the quantum **state** of your system at all. Instead, it is a pure property of the **Hamiltonian** (or Lindbladian) of the system.

The fact that you have strong coupling or vacuum Rabi *splitting* does tell you something about the dynamics of the system though. Specifically, it tells you that already a single photon in the strongly coupled mode will cause Rabi *oscillations* of your two-level system. The latter could also be seen as an alternative definition of strong light-matter coupling.

Note that this argument is about the light-matter coupling between a single mode and a two-level system. Effective strong coupling in multi-level systems is a whole different story and can be induced by external laser fields, such that this does depend on the laser power to some extent.

Comment: Thank you for clear answer. Could you please refer to some resource to learn more about the concept of field volume. Still unable to grasp its significance in the entire light-matter coupling scheme.

Comment: @avi0105 thanks for the accept! The most detailed and advanced discussion on mode volumes that I know of is: https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.5769. If you’re interested in a more basic intro, any textbook on cavity QED should have something on it or try googling “Purcell factor”.